# Quickblox Chat app: new message received should fire the appropriate uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, chat, quickblox

I'm currently developing a chat app using Quickblox for the backend. All works fine except for when a new message is received in didReceiveRemoteNotification the application state is checked for inactive and active states. If in the active state a UIAlertView is fired with an option to view the new message or ignore. Ignore will save the incoming message to CustomObjects while view should fire open the appropriate uitableviewcell of the sender of the message which in turn opens the appropriate chatview of the sender.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
// the user clicked OK
if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    QBCOCustomObject *object = [QBCOCustomObject customObject];
    object.className = @"Messages"; // your Class name
    // object fields
    [object.fields setObject:message forKey:@"Message_Text"];
    [object.fields setObject:sender forKey:@"Sender_ID"];
    [object.fields setObject:file forKey:@"Audio_Ref"];
    [QBCustomObjects createObject:object delegate:self];

}else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    //[self prepareToSegue: self.thisUserInfo ];
    // Download rich contentx
    [QBContent TDownloadFileWithBlobID:[file integerValue] delegate:self];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"fireTableCell"
                                                        object:msgArray];
}
```

}

// in UserView

```
-(void) fireTableCell: (NSNotification*) notification {
// takes in an array with the sender and message received
messageIn = [notification.object objectAtIndex:0];
QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
user.login = [notification.object objectAtIndex:1];

NSLog(@" * * the sender and message are %@ and %@", user.login, messageIn);

// load the chatview
NSLog(@"  * * * The dict is %@", dict);

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
EmojiViewController *controller = (EmojiViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chatView"];
controller.opponent = user;
//controller.messages = [[NSMutableArray array]init];
[controller.messages addObject:messageIn];
[controller.messagesTableView reloadData];
if (controller.presentingViewController == nil) {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

}

all of the above works as expected only when the chatview is pushed it is a new instance of this view that is created and not the existing so it appears that the message history is deleted. Can someone please advise me on where I'm going wrong? Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Method instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: creates a new instance of controller. So if You already has the needed instance then try to instantiate Your controller from storyboard You will have two different instances of Your controller.

Thus You have one message per controller instance.

Here I made for the sake of test in method viewDidLoad: got an instance of current controller from storyboard (Look at addresses of instances):

http://gyazo.com/7adc254fdd168803a1883791b63e9be2

Comment: Thanks Mixei, this still instantiates a blank view when it should contain a message history.